# Code for new flooring over gas lines

Tags: plumbing, flooring, gas

I am installing new flooring in a condo.

The condo association removed the old floor heating in favor of vent heating.

However, the copper what I assume to be gas lines (or water lines are sticking out of the old floor slightly and I want to cut them flush and install the flooring right over them.

Is there any code I am violating by doing this?

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly (when functional) hot water (or antifreeze, but mostly water), not gas. And if the system is abandoned and disconnected, neither.

Answer (score 2):

That pipe is already left open and surely not active or charged. Cutting it again will not be a problem, since it is no more than cutting it again slightly lower than what it is already.

If you want to go the safest route, since the floor is being redone anyway, remove enough of the existing floor to cut it below the existing floor to place a self sealing cap over it like Sharkbite (r) or similar brands. Please note, to do this the cut needs to be cleanly done, in order for the seal to be effective.

Comment: Also, it appears that there is a hole on the far side of the pipe from the photographer. To get a good seal, it would need to be cut below this hole.